# Fractional Swing UI scale not supported in Java under Linux

Tags: java, swing, hidpi

I would like to influence the UI scale of a standard Swing application with default L&F. Unfortunately scaling factor 1.0 is too small and 2.0 is too big. In my Linux fractional scaling factors are simply ignored. I searched already but can not find any solution to make it work. The scale is working for 1 or 2 but not in between:

–Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.5

Java is 1.15 but it does not matter in any way, I tried different flavors already. The Linux is a Ubuntu with XFCE window manager.